# How to tunnel all traffic through openconnect

Tags: networking, vpn, vpnc

I need to connect through cisco VPN: anyconnect. I found few articles ([example](http://www.humans-enabled.com/2011/06/how-to-connect-ubuntu-linux-to-cisco.html)) describing how to do that using openconnect and network-manager-openconnect. I installed both, configured the VPN connection, and it seem to work. The problem is, that when I surf to "what is my ip" service, I see the old IP instead of the one provided by the VPN.
When I try to connect using other VPN (openvpn) to other server, it just works as expected.
Does anyone know what can I read\do in order to solve the problem?
I want my public IP address to be provided by the VPN. 
Thanks.